# Convert Audio Nodes from Web Audio API to play in same quality with Expo Webview for IOS

Tags: webview, expo, web-audio-api, pitch-shifting

I'm using currently writing a mobile app on Expo that loads music files into a Webview and enables pitching their music key.
I'm utilizing this repo for that: `https://github.com/olvb/phaze`, which works with AudioWorkletNodes and the waves-audio library.

AudioWorkletNodes play in IOS Webviews, however the quality sounds more like it's played from a radio in the 20s.

I tested with a HTMLAudioElements and it worked fine on the Webview, so now I'm thinking how I could convert my AudioWorklet into HTMLAudio to maintain a good quality for my playback.

What's the way to go here?

Some Code below to understand how the audio file is dealt with in the repo:

```
const wavesAudio = require('waves-audio');
const wavesLoaders = require('waves-loaders');

let audioContext = wavesAudio.audioContext;
let loader = new wavesLoaders.AudioBufferLoader();

 const buffer = await loader.load('./track.mp3');
 let [playerEngine, phaseVocoderNode] = await setupEngine(buffer);
 let playControl = new wavesAudio.PlayControl(playerEngine);

// playControl enables us to play the AudioWorklet
// should we process our Audioworklet into a different format now?



async function setupEngine(buffer) {
  let playerEngine = new wavesAudio.PlayerEngine(buffer);
  playerEngine.buffer = buffer;
  playerEngine.cyclic = true;

  await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('phase-vocoder.js'); // processes file based on input
  let phaseVocoderNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'phase-vocoder-processor');
  playerEngine.connect(phaseVocoderNode);
  phaseVocoderNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  return [playerEngine, phaseVocoderNode];
}
```

Trying to convert audio into a workable audio format for Webview